# How to run multiple (2 or 3 at a time out of 500) Python Scripts stored in different files using multiple CPUs?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-3.8

I have a PC with multiple (4) processors.

I have the following code where I only want to allow '2' scripts to run at the same time.  Essentially, start 2, when 1 finishes start another, but have no more than 2 running at the same time.

Please help me come up with a code that can run 2 scripts at a time, the thoughts is one script would be on processor one, and the next script would be on processor 2.  I will adjust the limitation of '2' to something higher as I will upgrade to 8 processors, but I want to start with 2 so I understand the logic.  Thank you!

Here is my code and this seems to load all scripts simultaneously, not 2 at a time:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os

def run_script(script_file):
    print("Running script:", script_file)
    os.system("python " + script_file)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool(processes=2)    # start 2 worker processes
    #Hardcode Script Files for Now, Later Read Directory Contents and Build This Dynamically as it will grow alot
    script_files = ["scratch_6.py", "scratch_7.py", "scratch_8.py", "scratch_9.py", "scratch_10.py", "scratch_11.py", "scratch_12.py", "scratch_13.py"]
    processes = []
    for script_file in script_files:
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=run_script, args=(script_file,))
        processes.append(process)

    for process in processes:
        process.start()

    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

Comment: Given what you have so far, what is not working the way you hoped?

Comment: the code above seems to load all scripts simultaneously, not just 2 at a time that I expected by setting Pool(processes=2)

Comment: @ccc1997, The problem is you don't actually use the pool. It is not used implicitly. You have to explicitly use it. See `pydoc multiprocessing.pool`.

Comment: You can keep 2 tasks from a list running at a time very simply with **GNU Parallel**. Put `[gnu-parallel]` in the SO search box for examples. Try `parallel -j2 python script.py :::: FILEOFJOBS`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Semaphore` which can help you to limit the number of processes running simultaneously.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Semaphore

.
.
.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    max_processes = 2  # Max number of processes you want to run simultaneously
    semaphore = Semaphore(max_processes)
```

Comment: Yes, a semaphore could be used, but the O.P. is wondering why their use of `multiprocessing.Pool()` doesn't limit the number of concurrently executing processes. So I'm downvoting your answer because it doesn't address the question.

Comment: @KurtisRader AFAIK  `Pool()` class in Python does not limit the number of concurrently executing processes by default. The reason behind this is because the `Pool` is designed to be efficient for parallelizing tasks